# How to set default value in Select Component?

Tags: reactjs, carbon-design-system

On `React Carbon Select component` I want to have a default selected option, which can be changed, of course.
In general my goal is to implement edit functionality.
 It means user should be able to change already selected option.
I tried with adding the `value` property directly in `Select` like `value={defaultSelected}` or `defaultValue={defaultSelected}` but it didn't work.

Code example.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Select, SelectItem } from '@carbon/react';

const options = [
  {
    value: 'apple',
    text: 'Apple ',
  },
  {
    value: 'banana',
    text: 'Banana ',
  },
  {
    value: 'kiwi',
    text: 'Kiwi ',
  },
];

const SelectCarbon = ({defaultSelected}) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState();

  const onChange = e => {
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      fruit: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  console.log('formData', formData);

  return (
    <>
      {defaultSelected}
      <Select id="select-fruits" onChange={onChange} value={defaultSelected}>
        <SelectItem text="select Option" value="" />
        {options.map(option => (
          <SelectItem
            key={option.value}
            text={option.value}
            value={option.value}
          />
        ))}
      </Select>
    </>
  );
};

export default SelectCarbon;
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
fruit: options[0].value
});
```

And note that `formDate` should be an object not array.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But I am not sure, if it could work

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution conditionally showing either default value if nothing is selected or selected value.

And in order show the default value initially, I wrapped in formData in `useEffect`.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      fruit: defaultSelected,
    });
  }, [defaultSelected]);

  const onChange = e => {
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      fruit: e.target.value ?? defaultSelected,
    });
  };

  console.log('formData', formData);

  return (
    <>
      {defaultSelected}
      <Select
        id="select-fruits"
        onChange={onChange}
        defaultValue={defaultSelected}>
        <SelectItem text="select Option" value="" />
        {options.map(option => (
          <SelectItem
            key={option.value}
            text={option.value}
            value={option.value}
          />
        ))}
      </Select>
    </>
  );
};

export default SelectCarbon;
```